# Why doesn't discord.py let me edit an embed?

Tags: python, discord.py

i'm trying to edit a message in discord.py and add to it an embed.

```
tutMsg = await c.send("Avvio tutorial...")

validTutReactions = ["◀️", "▶️", "❌"]

for i in validTutReactions:
    await tutMsg.add_reaction(i)

embed = discord.Embed(title="prova")
try:
    await tutMsg.edit(embed=embed)
except:
    console.print_exception()
```

In theory there is no problem with this code, however it doesn't work. It says that i can't send an empty message. What can I do? In other parts of the code it works fine...

Here is the error (yes, I use Rich  so it's looking fancy)
[image: this is the error that i get]

Comment: What are the reactions for?

Comment: @Dominik for moving between different embeds. It will be implemented later

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine, maybe post more information?

Comment: Probably an Embed with only the title is considered an empty message.

Comment: Actually the code works on any machine except my computer. I tried this on my laptop and it worked perfectly fine